# Can you convert an .accdr file to .accdb?

Tags: database, ms-access

I don't have access the original executable files but only the runtime versions of the Access files. I need to change a key core function of a database and I cannot access the core functionality. Do I need the original files or can I work with what I have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.accdr` file extension does not tell you whether the database is actually ACCDB or ACCDE format.  If it's ACCDE, source code was removed and you can not use it for further development.

Find out which you have:

1. Make of copy of the `.accdr` and rename that copy with an `.accdb` file extension.
2. Open the `.accdb` in Access.
3. Attempt to open any module and view its source code.

If step #3 is successful, your database is an ACCDB and you can make design changes to it.

If step #3 fails, the database is probably an ACCDE.  You will need to find the original ACCDB to use for your design changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gord, it turned out the database was ACCDE. (Oh well can't win them all!). Your explanation was very helpful :)