# Access 365 and accdr file

Tags: ms-access, office365, ms-access-2016

EDIT:

I have tried 32 and 64 bits accdr and accde files.  They work great on my Office 2016 installation but I still get the "unrecognized format" error.

Any more clues?  I think I saw that a special switch was needed to start Access 365 in runtime mode.  Does that ring a bell to anyone?

I have an accdr file that is used by a bunch of clients (non profit orgs).  One of them has Office 365 Business edition and it just won't open the accdr file, giving the "Unrecognized Database Format" error.

Can that be fixed through a switch in the command line?  Do I need to create the accdb in O365 (it was created in 2016)?  Can O365 be 32 bits?  The accdr was done on an x64 office installation.

Comment: Office 365 can (internally) be 2016 or 2019, and yes it absolutely can be 32-bit. That would be my guess as source of the problem. Especially if the .accdr is actually an .accde (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392307/can-you-convert-an-accdr-file-to-accdb) to find out what it is).

Comment: *I have tried 32 and 64 bits accdr and accde files. They work great on my Office 2016 installation* - really? I thought you cannot install both 32 and 64bit Office on one computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the file is not corrupted and that it's working on another machine. If the file is OK, then download and install `Microsoft Access 2016 Runtime`, and the file will work.

Download the right edition for your `OS`. 32-bit or 64-bit.

[Microsoft Access 2016 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040)

**Note**: If the file was created with Access 64-bit it cannot work on 32-bit `OS`.

Comment: See my edits, but mainly, I have tried 32 and 64 bits accdr and accde files. They work great on my Office 2016 installation but I still get the "unrecognized format" error.  I am baffled...

Comment: You have to create the `accde` \ `accdr` file using a `32-bit` version of access. It will work.